# Bash recognize variables within string

Tags: xml, string, bash, variables, replace

I have a bash script that is called with a varying number of parameters, for example:

```
sh ./test.sh p1 p2 p3
```

Basically, the script looks in an XML-File what it should do with these parameters, and then executes the command string. An example XML-File:

```
...
<command name='echo'>
  <exec>echo 1st parameter: $p1 2nd parameter: $p2 3rd parameter: $p3</exec>
</command>
...
```

The XML file is parsed fine using xmlstarlet this way:

```
command=$(xml sel -t -m "data/command[@name='$1']/exec" -v '.' /usr/share/data.xml)
```

(assuming $1 is "echo")

After that, the variable `command` contains `echo 1st parameter: $p1 2nd parameter: $2 3rd parameter: $p3`. Nice. But when I try to execute that command string by simply typing `$command` in the script, bash doesn't replace `$p1`,  `$p2` and `p3` with their corresponding values, but instead simply prints:

```
1st parameter: $1 2nd parameter: $2 3rd parameter: $3
```

Since I don't know how many parameters are involved, simply replacing any occurences of $* in the string with their value doesn't solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't do this. It is not going to work well. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for why it will have trouble. And doing it at all requires `eval` which is unpleasant.

Comment: Okay, you're probably right. But what other method could I use to organize all available commands, so I can easily add new commands afterwards without changing the code? Is it possible in another scripting language? It must not necessarily be bash in my case...

Comment: If you want bash just use bash and create functions for each "command" that take the correct arguments. Don't play games with storage in xml as strings/etc.